# How do you iterate through a fixed array or lookup table rows through FactoryGirl sequences?

Tags: loops, sequence, factory-bot, skip, lookup-tables

[FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl)'s `sequence` method lets you generate unique data when being called multiple times by maintaining an incrementing counter. However, let's say I have a table where the primary key IDs aren't continuous, or just an arbitrary array of values I'd like successive calls to iterate through, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
sequence(:brand) do |n|
  brands = Brand.all.sort{ |brand| brand.id }
  brands[(n - 1) % brands.size]
end
```